# Why was there an error when importing data to phpMyAdmin because there is a difference in MySQL syntax?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm currently importing a MySQL database.
But when I import, an error message appears as below:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`tglmsk`' at line 1

Here is the MySQL syntax:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    VIEW `cetak`  AS
    SELECT `daily`.`idu` AS `idu`, `daily`.`nik` AS `nik`, `daily`.`nama` AS `nama`, `daily`.`kdstore` AS `kdstore`, `daily`.`nmstore` AS `nmstore`, `daily`.`tglmsk` AS `tglmsk`, `daily`.`shift` AS `shift`, `daily`.`start` AS `start`, `daily`.`end` AS `end`, `daily`.`event` AS `event`, `daily`.`ln` AS `ln`, `daily`.`jkerja` AS `jkerja`, `daily`.`tjkerja` AS `tjkerja`, `daily`.`tl` AS `tl`, `daily`.`ulembur` AS `ulembur`, `daily`.`uhr` AS `uhr`, `daily`.`uln` AS `uln`, `daily`.`ulembur` + `daily`.`uhr` + `daily`.`uln` AS `pembayaran`, `daily`.`periode` AS `periode`, `daily`.`tgl` AS `tgl`, if(`daily`.`tgl` <= 15,1,2) AS `ctk`, `daily`.`acc` AS `acc`
    FROM `daily`
    ORDER BY `daily`.`tglmsk` ASC`tglmsk` ;
```

I'm migrating from the old MySQL and phpMyAdmin to the latest.

Comment: What is your question? The error message clearly indicates the syntax error at the end of your `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Why is that an error?

Comment: This code suffers from alias incontinence and I can't tell if asc in ORDER BY `daily`.`tglmsk` ASC`tglmsk` ; is a typo for as but mysql thinks there are 2 orderby clause which therefore be comma separated.

Comment: ``ORDER BY `daily`.`tglmsk` ASC`tglmsk` ;`` - remove the `tglmsk` after `ASC`.

Comment: @P.Salmon the _"alias incontinence"_ is the "normalized" form returned by `SHOW CREATE VIEW ...`

Comment: I exported this database from online hosting. Why is the error occurring while online hosting is fine?